# cannot import name 'FPDF' from partially initialized module 'fpdf' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, fpdf

estimada comunidad.
Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de importar unas librerias de python:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
```

Error: cannot import name 'FPDF' from partially initialized module 'fpdf' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Hem.. como se llamma tu archivo que ejecuta eso?

Comment: generate_reports

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema intentando migrar modelos que llamaban a otros modelos que también se estaban migrando. La solución por la que opté: migrar los modelos uno por uno.

Answer (score 1):

Este error ocurría seguido antes de la versión 3.5, donde si tratabas de importar un modulo que ya existe en el registro de módulos sys.modules te daría un error de importación cíclica. Luego de esta versión se creó soporte para que esto no ocurra o por lo menos "no debería ocurrir". ([aquí la lista de cambios al respecto si te gusta la historia](https://bugs.python.org/issue17636))

En versiones posteriores a la 3.5 me parece bastante raro que suceda (*por lo que e visto*) ya que si importas un moduloA dentro de un moduloB y importas el moduloB dentro del moduloA, el interprete al ver este "ping-pong" de importaciones simplemente lee las importaciones una vez y la próxima vez que entra al modulo ignora el import y lee las demás lineas de código:

```
#moduloA.py
import moduloB
print('modulo A')

#moduloB.py
import moduloA
print('modulo B')
```

Ejecutando moduloA.py: dará el siguiente resultado

```
modulo A
modulo B
modulo A
>>>
```

Donde

1. se ejecuta moduloA e importa ModuloB
2. se ejecuta moduloB e importa ModuloA
3. se ejecuta moduloA, el interprete al ver que se intenta importar ModuloB (que ya existe esta en el registro de modulos) ignora la linea y se rompe el ciclo.

**Posibles soluciones:**

Antes que nada me gustaría decir que intente ejecutar código usando el mismo "from fpdf import FPDF" y me funciono a la perfección, por tanto tuve que crear una situación que me de un error cíclico para comprobar...

**1)** importar todo el modulo fpdf:

Problema: vas a cargar todo lo que este dentro del modulo...

> ```
> import fpdf
>
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>
> import os
>     
>     
> #O bien:
>
> from fpdf import *
>
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>
> import os
> ```

**2)** Cambiar el nombre de los archivos.
Es posible que el nombre de un archivo python dentro de tu proyecto comparta el nombre de un modulo. (algo tan simple puede ser muy problematico).

Existe otra solución y es hacer la importación dentro de una función, es util si el modulo es rara vez usado y resulta una "carga" importante, pero es [difícil de mantener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095071/in-python-what-happens-when-you-import-inside-of-a-function) así que no lo pondré con las demás...

*Espero que te haya servido de ayuda~*

Comment: Voto a favor, excelente respuesta, explicas muy bien el error y como se soluciona

Comment: Gracias bro, eres un gran facilitador 

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que esta importando `FPDF` de `fpdf`, pero `FPDF` importa `fpdf` así que es una importación circular, eso no debe hacerlo

Comment: Gracias!! Me podrías con un ejemplo de como quedaría? please.

Comment: `import fpdf` ?

Comment: Depende de como este escrita la biblioteca.
Esto podrá ilustrar lo que sucede https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Answer (score -1):

Tuve el mismo problema, mi problema fue que mi archivo se llamaba "fpdf.py". Renombre mi archivo a "app.py" y problema solucionado.

Comment: leíste los comentarios? pregunte eso.